# Index was out of range in gridview row

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to block the previous clicked value but am getting the error array out of bound index error please help me out from these problem.lblWelcomeName.Text is facultyname that is displayed in label in the aspx page.All other value am reading from database.

```
protected void createbtnclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    var datedif = new List<DateTime>();
                    var subject1 = new List<string>();
                    var subject2 = new List<string>();
                    var subject3 = new List<string>();
                    var subject4 = new List<string>();
                    var subject5 = new List<string>();
                    var hour1 = new List<bool>();
                    var hour2 = new List<bool>();
                    var hour3 = new List<bool>();
                    var hour4 = new List<bool>();
                    var hour5 = new List<bool>();
                    var faculty1 = new List<string>();
                    var faculty2 = new List<string>();
                    var faculty3 = new List<string>();
                    var faculty4 = new List<string>();
                    var faculty5 = new List<string>();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select datedif from test", con2);
                    con2.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        datedif.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["datedif"]));
                    }
                    con2.Close();
                    DateTime[] datelist = datedif.ToArray();
                    int datearray = datedif.ToArray().Length;
                    for (int i = 0; i < datearray; i++)
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select subject1,subject2,subject3,subject4,subject5,faculty1,faculty2,faculty3,faculty4,faculty5,hour1,hour2,hour3,hour4,hour5 from test where datedif='" + datelist[i] + "'", con2);
                        con2.Open();
                        SqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                        while (rdr1.Read())
                        {
                            subject1.Add(rdr1["subject1"].ToString());
                            subject2.Add(rdr1["subject2"].ToString());
                            subject3.Add(rdr1["subject3"].ToString());
                            subject4.Add(rdr1["subject4"].ToString());
                            subject5.Add(rdr1["subject5"].ToString());
                            subject1.Add(rdr1["subject1"].ToString());

                            faculty1.Add(rdr1["faculty1"].ToString());
                            faculty2.Add(rdr1["faculty2"].ToString());
                            faculty3.Add(rdr1["faculty3"].ToString());
                            faculty4.Add(rdr1["faculty4"].ToString());
                            faculty5.Add(rdr1["faculty5"].ToString());

                            hour1.Add(Convert.ToBoolean(rdr1["hour1"].ToString()));
                            hour2.Add(Convert.ToBoolean(rdr1["hour2"].ToString()));
                            hour3.Add(Convert.ToBoolean(rdr1["hour3"].ToString()));
                            hour4.Add(Convert.ToBoolean(rdr1["hour4"].ToString()));
                            hour5.Add(Convert.ToBoolean(rdr1["hour5"].ToString()));
                        }
                        con2.Close();
                    }
                    string[] faculty1array = faculty1.ToArray();
                    string[] faculty2array = faculty2.ToArray();
                    string[] faculty3array = faculty3.ToArray();
                    string[] faculty4array = faculty4.ToArray();
                    string[] faculty5array = faculty5.ToArray();

                    string[] subject1array = subject1.ToArray();
                    string[] subject2array = subject2.ToArray();
                    string[] subject3array = subject3.ToArray();
                    string[] subject4array = subject4.ToArray();
                    string[] subject5array = subject5.ToArray();

                    bool[] hour1array = hour1.ToArray();
                    bool[] hour2array = hour2.ToArray();
                    bool[] hour3array = hour3.ToArray();
                    bool[] hour4array = hour4.ToArray();
                    bool[] hour5array = hour5.ToArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < datearray; i++)
                    {
                        if (faculty1array[i] == lblWelcomeName.Text)
                        {
                            var chk1 = (CheckBox)Gv1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chkHour1");
                            chk1.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        if (faculty2array[i] == lblWelcomeName.Text)
                        {
                            var chk2 = (CheckBox)Gv1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chkHour2");
                            chk2.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        if (faculty3array[i] == lblWelcomeName.Text)
                        {
                            var chk3 = (CheckBox)Gv1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chkHour3");
                            chk3.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        if (faculty4array[i] == lblWelcomeName.Text)
                        {
                            var chk4 = (CheckBox)Gv1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chkHour4");
                            chk4.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        if (faculty5array[i] == lblWelcomeName.Text)
                        {
                            var chk5 = (CheckBox)Gv1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chkHour5");
                            chk5.Enabled = false;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Replace `Gv1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl` witrh `Gv1.Rows[i].FindControl`. You don't need to use FindControl on a cell, it's sufficient to use it on the `GridViewRow` since that is the `NamingContainer`.

Comment: how you can think that number of item in datearray is equivalent to numbers of row of grid.

Comment: still the same error

Comment: am bounding the value so it wont go maximum

Comment: @RavintherM: i know, was just a comment to improve your code not to fix your issue ;)